# Unattended Scripts to connect

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0, azure-powershell, powershell-4.0

For the MFA enabled account I need to run the PowerShell scripts without any user intersection for the below connections

1.Connect-MsolService

2.Connect-SPOService

Please help to get the steps to connect.

For the MFA enabled account I need to run the PowerShell scripts without any user intersection for the below connections

1.Connect-MsolService

2.Connect-SPOService

3.Connect-MicrosoftTeams

Please help to get the steps to connect.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You should not use a user account to run unattended scripts, you will not be able to respond to the MFA prompt (and disable MFA is not the solution). The solution to this is to use an Azure Service Principle to run your scripts. These are service accounts intended to be used for non-interactive interaction with Azure.

See [here](https://docs.serverless360.com/docs/what-is-a-service-principal-1) for details on how to create and use them.

Comment: Will be able to connect MSOLservice with this authentication

Comment: Yes, you can use a service principle for this